# Return the record modified by UPDATE TOP 1

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql

I have a C# application and would like to return the record updated by the TSQL  UPDATE TOP 1 
without doing a 2nd query. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OUTPUT`, for example:

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (Id int not null)
UPDATE TOP (1) [YourTable]
SET [YourColumn] = newValue
OUTPUT inserted.Id INTO @tmp

SELECT * FROM @tmp
```

(add more columns to suit)

Note the `INTO` here is necessary in the *general* case to avoid issues with triggers; otherwise it is common to see:

> The target table 'YourTable' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

Comment: (`OUTPUT` requires SQL Server 2005 or later)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

```
update top (1) T
set Col = 'x'
output inserted.*
from YourTable as T
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its possible .

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
EmpID int NOT NULL,
OldVacationHours int,
NewVacationHours int,
ModifiedDate datetime);
UPDATE TOP (10) HumanResources.Employee
SET VacationHours = VacationHours * 1.25,
ModifiedDate = GETDATE() 
OUTPUT inserted.BusinessEntityID,
   deleted.VacationHours,
   inserted.VacationHours,
   inserted.ModifiedDate
INTO @MyTableVar;
--Display the result set of the table variable.
SELECT EmpID, OldVacationHours, NewVacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM @MyTableVar;
GO 
--Display the result set of the table.
SELECT TOP (10) BusinessEntityID, VacationHours, ModifiedDate
FROM HumanResources.Employee;
GO
```

refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx#CaptureResults